# Transitioning out doesn't work when moving mouse away using hover:after

Tags: css, flexbox

I created an underline that opacity goes in but doesn't go out when moving out the mouse on the element and I want the transition of it going out as well when I hover away.

```
.underline-hover-effect:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-color: #6415ff;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease;
}

.underline-hover-effect:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This just results of transitioning in the opacity but not transitioning out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width` collapses to zero when you're not hovered because you've declared it only in the hover state.

Move the `left` and `width` rules into the non-hovered selector so it's always the same size and in the same place.

```css
.underline-hover-effect {
  position: relative;
}

.underline-hover-effect::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-color: #6415ff;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.underline-hover-effect:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline-hover-effect">hello</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you so much I didn't expect it to be that simple.